# How can I know the networkStatus of all queries in ApolloClient globally?

Tags: networking, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to show preloader when a networkStatus is in-flight.

I know that every query returns its own networkStatus, but in my application there are so many different queries. I want to have a way of handling all the networkStatus for all the queries, globally.

What I'm wanting to know inside my code is the answer for: "Is there any query pending on the network?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there's no way of doing that, at least not easily/built-in. You could request this as a feature on https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests.

Depending on what you are wanting to achieve, using a middleware/afterware on your `HttpLink` could be sufficient, e.g:

```js
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';

const middleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  console.log('Starting', operation);

  return forward(operation);
});

const afterware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  return forward(operation).map(response => {
    console.log('Completed', operation);

    return response;
  });
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    middleware,
    afterware,
    new HttpLink({ ... }),
  ]),
});
```

The `middleware` will be called before each request, and the `afterware`, after. You can read more about links at: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/.

Alternatively, looking at some of the APIs that Apollo exposes publicly, I was able to make the check on this "unofficial" way:

```js
function queriesInFlight() {
  // client is your ApolloClient instance
  const { queryManager } = client;

  return Object.keys(queryManager.queryStore.getStore()).filter(queryId =>
    queryManager.checkInFlight(queryId),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: In ApolloClient V3, queryManager.queryStore.getStore() doesn't seem to work anymore, but if you access queryManager.queries that has all the info about cached queries you could possibly want

Comment: @Ascendant: queryManager is private and I get an error trying to access it. :|

Comment: @Eraldo Yeah, it's private so you're not "supposed" to access it. But you might also find what you're looking for in ROOT_QUERY