# Managing multiple calls to the same Apollo mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

So taking a look at the Apollo useMutation example in the docs https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#tracking-loading-and-error-states

```
function Todos() {
...
  const [
    updateTodo,
    { loading: mutationLoading, error: mutationError },
  ] = useMutation(UPDATE_TODO);
...

  return data.todos.map(({ id, type }) => {
    let input;

    return (
      <div key={id}>
        <p>{type}</p>
        <form
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            updateTodo({ variables: { id, type: input.value } });

            input.value = '';
          }}
        >
          <input
            ref={node => {
              input = node;
            }}
          />
          <button type="submit">Update Todo</button>
        </form>
        {mutationLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
        {mutationError && <p>Error :( Please try again</p>}
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

This seems to have a major flaw (imo), updating any of the todos will show the loading state for every single todo, not just the one that has the pending mutation.

[image]

And this seems to stem from a larger problem: there's no way to track the state of multiple calls to the same mutation. So even if I did want to only show the loading state for the todos that were actually loading, there's no way to do that since we only have the concept of "is loading" not "is loading for todo X".

Besides manually tracking loading state outside of Apollo, the only decent solution I can see is splitting out a separate  component, use that to render each Todo instead of having that code directly in the Todos component, and having those components each initialize their own mutation. I'm not sure if I think that's a good or bad design, but in either case it doesn't feel like I should have to change the structure of my components to accomplish this.

And this also extends to error handling. What if I update one todo, and then update another while the first update is in progress. If the first call errors, will that be visible at all in the `data` returned from `useMutation`? What about the second call?

Is there a native Apollo way to fix this? And if not, are there options for handling this that may be better than the ones I've mentioned?

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/v3mn68xxvy

Comment: I'm kind of confused by your question. It's not that apollo doesn't have unique / multiple loading states, its your code that only has one `mutationLoading`. state that you pass to your todos. the same state gets passed to all of them, so even if apollo had something you want, your code still wouldn't be making use of it. it would have to be something like `loadingId === id` at the very least. Anyways your problem is completely solved by calling `useMutation` at the item level, not the list level. that's not a workaround, it's perfectly sane solution

Comment: on another note, apollo does keep track of which query is running. so you could combine your `isLoading` with the knowledge of which variable was being passed to the mutation, though I would consider that to be a much worse solution

Comment: I know that the current code wouldn't take advantage of any per-item state returned from useMutation. I know you'd wanna do something like `loadingId === id`, but `loadingId` isn't available.

Comment: As for "you could combine your isLoading with the knowledge of which variable was being passed to the mutation", how would that work if multiple mutations were in progress at the same time? `loading` would mean nothing if I don't know exactly which mutations are the ones actually `loading`.

Comment: And as for pushing the mutation down to the item level, I don't disagree that that's a sane solution, but it does have drawbacks. Namely, the parent component loses any insight into the loading state of its items. Say I wanted to surface loading state for the todo items in the `Todos` component (for some reason) I would either lose that ability, or need to add some sort of `onLoading` callback to the `Todo` components, and still manually keep track of loading state in `Todos`.

Comment: that's a fair point. You should be able to get the variables used in the mutation `const [mutation, { loading, error, variables } = useMutation(..)` though for some in the docs it only shows that for `useQuery`. Hmm there is an issue there though as you mention. I'm trying to think of what apollo would need to implement here to satisfy this.. it would have to return a list of pending queries. it might do that actually somewhere

Comment: Sounds like you want something like a list of all in flight queries, here's a recent possibly relevant questions https://stackoverflow.com/a/58029443/3225108

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Admittedly, the example in the docs should be rewritten to be much clearer. There's a number of other issues with it too.

The `useQuery` and `useMutation` hooks are only designed for tracking the loading, error and result state of a single operation at a time. The operation's variables might change, it might be refetched or appended onto using `fetchMore`, but ultimately, you're still just dealing with that one operation. You can't use a single hook to keep track of separate states of multiple operations. To do that, you need multiple hooks.

In the case of a form like this, if the input fields are known ahead of time, then you can just split the hook out into multiple ones within the same component:

```
const [updateA, { loading: loadingA, error: errorA }] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION)
const [updateB, { loading: loadingB, error: errorB }] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION)
const [updateC, { loading: loadingC, error: errorC }] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION)
```

If you're dealing with a variable number of fields, then we *have* to break out this logic into a separate because we can't declare hooks inside a loop. This is less of a limitation of the Apollo API and simply a side-effect of the magic behind hooks themselves.

```
const ToDo = ({ id, type }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const options = { variables = { id, type: value } }
  const const [updateTodo, { loading, error }] = useMutation(UPDATE_TODO, options)
  const handleChange = event => setValue(event.target.value)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{type}</p>
      <form onSubmit={updateTodo}>
        <input
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">Update Todo</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

// back in our original component...

return data.todos.map(({ id, type }) => (
  <Todo key={id} id={id} type={type] />
))
```